# pre-commit check or Remote-run missing with Github setup & Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, teamcity, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

Just to quote as an example one can submit a remote-run with some tool like TeamCity (similar to Jenkins) where it will apply delta/patch on what user is trying to commit & produces result whether changes is good from set-of configured checks for that project.

With Github & Jenkins, can such validation be achieved with any plugins out there?, which will avoid breaking a build?

I know with pull-request & status check one can achieve similar end-result. But without commit/push to remote repo of Git - is there a way Jenkins can handle this validation & produce initial result ??

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to have GitHub perform checks on data it doesn't have, so if you don't push the data to the remote server, GitHub won't know anything about it and therefore will do nothing.

Jenkins does have [a REST API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) that you could use to do this, provided you equipped each developer with appropriate credentials.  However, this is not a common situation and wouldn't be a recommended configuration.

You'd be better off with a script in the repository that users *could* install as a hook or invoke from a hook that would perform the testing you want.  If your CI jobs run a [script in your repository](https://github.com/github/scripts-to-rule-them-all), then sharing code between them should be easy.

Note that you shouldn't mandate pre-commit hooks, since they can interfere with advanced users (who may make intentionally incomplete temporary commits) and they can be disabled by users.  Any sort of required checks should be done as part of CI, where policy can be enforced appropriately.